# Looping and Animating with setTimeOut

Tags: jquery

Can anybody help me understand this piece of code line by line

```
var $elements = $('#One, #Two, #Three, #Four');
function anim_loop(index) {
    $elements.eq(index).fadeIn(1000, function() {
        var $self = $(this);
        setTimeout(function() {
            $self.fadeOut(1000);
            anim_loop((index + 1) % $elements.length);
        }, 3000);
    });
}
anim_loop(0); // start with the first element
```

Complete example http://jsfiddle.net/w5YHY/

Specifically I have these questions:

Why use setTimeOut here?
What does var $self = $(this); do?
What does anim_loop((index + 1) % $elements.length); mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function anim_loop is called recursively and will load an element by index in `$elements`. At the same time the currently shown element will fade out.

```
function anim_loop(index) {//function takes an integer index
    $elements.eq(index)//get the element at index
             .fadeIn(1000, function() {//fade in element over 1000ms and call passed function when done fading in
                var $self = $(this); //wrap current element with jQuery so we can use helpers
                setTimeout(function() {//create a timeout when the current element is being displayed
                    $self.fadeOut(1000);//hide current element
                    var nextIndex = (index + 1) % $elements.length; //next index in $elements (currentIndex add 1 mod length)
                    anim_loop(nextIndex);//load next element
                }, 3000);
            });
}
```

Comment: Why use setTimeOut here?
What does var $self = $(this); do?
What does anim_loop((index + 1) % $elements.length); mean?

Comment: @user2983762 `setTimeout` delays executing a function for a period (see a doc). I added some more comments and variables so you can see whats happening more clearly.

Comment: Thanks so much. I have two more questions. (1) How does (index + 1) % $elements.length; work and (2) what do you mean by wrap current element with jQuery so we can use helpers. What helpers?

Comment: For 1) google (javascript) modulus, 2) lets you use the `.fadeOut()` helper as `this` is currently set to the element about to be hidden. Also lets you use any other `jQuery` helpers see http://jquery.com

Comment: I just googled and found that doing $self = $(this) is used for caching. Is this the case here?

Comment: Yes, it's so you don't have to write `$(this)` every time (rewrapping this) you want to use a jQuery method.

Answer (score 0):

Get the element in the `index` position. '`fadeIn()`' means you are gonna show the element in `'1000' miliseconds (1 second)`. The block code inside the method its gonna do after `'1000' miliseconds`. So you have first. The variable self that is the element that you are looping. Second you have a '`setTimeOut()`' method, it means the block code inside it gonna work after `'3000' miliseconds`. Then, '`self.fadeOut(1000)`' will hide the current element and then the code will invoke the method again to do the work with the next element.

Answer (score 0):

Why use setTimeOut here?
=> `SettimeOut is used to make sure the element is displayed for only 3 sec's (3000), after 3sec's hide the element and get the next element in line.`

What does var $self = $(this); do?
`It get's reference to the member on which the current function is invoked.`

What does anim_loop((index + 1) % $elements.length); mean?

`This means: whatever the current index is + 1 = next element, Now if index is the last element currently it needs to get back to zero hence it's doing a modulus with the length which get's you back to the first element.`

The way modulus works is it returns only the remainder.